# Admin not working in localhost

Tags: admin

i am opening localhost/candle/admin in firefox, but The requested URL /candle/admin was not found on this server. error is coming. how i solve this problem? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use `localhost` as root url.
Use `127.0.0.1` or create a virtual host that has a dot in it. Something like `magento.local`.

And most probably you don't have the `mod_rewrite` enabled on your server.
Either enable it or call this url  `/candle/index.php/admin`

Comment: Thanks Marius,/candle/index.php/admin, this solution was absolutely right,

Comment: how can i enable mod_rewrite on my server

Comment: just google it : [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Comment: i think that solution is for Apache and i am using wampserver

Comment: WAMP = Windows Apache Mysql PHP

Answer (score 0):

Set in your database in `core_config_data` the following values :

`web/unsecure/base_url`and `web/secure/base_url` and you should be fine

Comment: i checked, values was already there

Answer (score 0):

Copy .htaccess file from:

> [Magento2 Root Directory]/pub/.htaccess

Paste .htaccess file to:

> [Magento2 Root Directory]/.htaccess